# Каким образом передать функции с параметрами в указатели на функции другой функции?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Хочу узнать, каким образом можно передать функции foo3, функции foo1 и foo2, которые во время вызова функции foo3, выполняли свои роли, а именно преобразовывали x из 1 в 10, а y из 2 в 20. Функция foo3 в свою очередь умножила x(10) и y(20) друг на друга. Функция foo3 НЕ РАБОЧАЯ.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int foo1(int& x) {
  return x = 10;
}

int foo2(int& y) {
  return y = 20;
}

int foo3(int (*name_func1)(int& x), int (*name_func2)(int& y)) {
  return name_func1(x) * name_func2(y);
} // Функция лишь пример, и требует в доработке

int main() {
  int x = 1, y = 2;
  int (*ptr_foo1)(int& x);
  int (*ptr_foo2)(int& y);

  cout << "Before calling functions via function pointers:\n";
  cout << "x + y = " << x + y << endl;
  cout << endl;

  ptr_foo1 = foo1;
  ptr_foo2 = foo2;

  ptr_foo1(x);
  ptr_foo2(y);

  cout << "After calling functions via function pointers:\n";
  cout << "x + y = " << x + y << endl;
  cout << endl;

  cout << "Simple multiplication:\n";
  cout << "x * y = " << x * y << endl;

  cout << "Multiplication with function pointer in function:\n";
  cout << "x * y = " << foo3(foo1(x), foo2(y)); // Ошибка...

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Следует добавить в функцию `foo3` еще два аргумента `int& x` и `int& y`

Comment: Заметьте, что в `int foo3(int (*name_func1)(int& x), int (*name_func2)(int& y))` и в `int (*ptr_foo1)(int& x); int (*ptr_foo2)(int& y);`, имена `x`,`y` игнорирются, и их можно не писать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int foo1(int& x) {
  return x = 10;
}

int foo2(int& y) {
  return y = 20;
}

int foo3(int (*name_func1)(int&), int (*name_func2)(int&), int& x, int& y) {
  return name_func1(x) * name_func2(y);
} // Функция лишь пример, и требует в доработке

int main() {
  int x = 1, y = 2;
  int (*ptr_foo1)(int&);
  int (*ptr_foo2)(int&);

  cout << "Before calling functions via function pointers:\n";
  cout << "x + y = " << x + y << endl;
  cout << endl;

  ptr_foo1 = foo1;
  ptr_foo2 = foo2;

  ptr_foo1(x);
  ptr_foo2(y);

  cout << "After calling functions via function pointers:\n";
  cout << "x + y = " << x + y << endl;
  cout << endl;

  cout << "Simple multiplication:\n";
  cout << "x * y = " << x * y << endl;

  cout << "Multiplication with function pointer in function:\n";
  cout << "x * y = " << foo3(foo1, foo2, x, y); // Ошибка...

  return 0;
}
```